# How do I make java wait for boolean to run funciton

Tags: java, android, timer, response

I'm sure this is pretty simple but I can't figure out and it sucks I'm up on suck on (what should be) an easy step.

ok. I have a method that runs one function that give a response. this method actually handles the uploading of the file so o it takes a second to give a response. I need this response in the following method. sendPicMsg needs to complete and then forward it's response to sendMessage. Please help.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(!uploadMsgPic.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            Log.v("response","Pic in storage");
            sendPicMsg();
                    sendMessage();
            }else{
                    sendMessage();
                }
```

1st Method

```
public void sendPicMsg(){ 
Log.v("response", "sendPicMsg Loaded");
if(!uploadMsgPic.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

  final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    AsyncHttpClient client3 = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params3 = new RequestParams();

    File file = new File(uploadMsgPic);

    try {
        File f = new File(uploadMsgPic.replace(".", "1."));
        f.createNewFile();

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file,400);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);


        params3.put("file", f);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    params3.put("email", preferences.getString("loggedin_user", ""));
    params3.put("webversion", "1");
    client3.post("http://*******.com/apiweb/******upload.php",params3, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String response) {
          Log.v("response", "Upload Complete");

          refreshChat();
        //responseString = response;
        Log.v("response","msgPic has been uploaded"+response);
        //parseChatMessages(response);
        response=picurl;
        uploadMsgPic = "";

        if(picurl!=null){
            Log.v("response","picurl is set");
        }
        if(picurl==null){
                Log.v("response", "picurl no ready");
                };

      }




  });

    sendMessage();

}                         


  }
```

2nd Method

```
public void sendMessage(){ 

  final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
  if(preferences.getString("Username", "").length()<=0){
      editText1.setText("");
      Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Please Login to send messages.", 2);
      return;
  }
    AsyncHttpClient  client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
        params.put("toid",user);
         params.put("action", "sendprivate");
    }else{
        params.put("room", preferences.getString("selected_room", "Adult Lobby"));
         params.put("action", "insert");

    }
    Log.v("response", "Sending message "+editText1.getText().toString());
params.put("message",editText1.getText().toString() );
params.put("media", picurl);

 params.put("email", preferences.getString("loggedin_user", ""));
params.put("webversion", "1");


  client.post("http://peekatu.com/apiweb/*********.php",params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String response) {

          refreshChat();
        //responseString = response;
        Log.v("response", response);
        //parseChatMessages(response);
        if(picurl!=null)
        Log.v("response", picurl);
      }



  });





  editText1.setText("");
    lv.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);

  }
```

Comment: How do I make sure response in ready before next function starting?

Comment: Looks like onSuccess() method is a callback, You could use a synchronizer(http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) while calling sendPicMsg() and call sendMessage() only when onSuccess() notifies the synchronizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need serial execution of background tasks.
What I do in the case is use a class that extends AsyncTask, takes some sort of listener in its constructor and calls the listener's callback in onPostExecute.

A quick example:

```
class ExampleTask<T,S,U> extends AsyncTask<T,S,U>
{
    public interface ExampleListener
    {
        public void onTaskCompleted(boolean success);
    }

    private ExampleListener mListener;

    public ExampleTask(ExampleListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(U result)
    {
        ...
        if (mListener != null)
        {
            mListener.onTaskCompleted(yourBooleanResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Just pass a new ExampleListener implementation that calls the second method.
Here's an implementation of the listener:

```
ExampleListener sendMessageListener = new ExampleListener()
{
    public void onTaskCompleted(boolean success)
    {
        if(success)
            sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I believe this solution may solve be but can I get a bit of clarification on how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't know where to start. Would you happen to have any examples?

Comment: I can't give you a full example due to a tight schedule. Edited the answer to include an example of the listener. Move the code from your first method to an ExampleTask's doInBackground method, pass in the listener in the constructor and you should be good to go!

Comment: anybody have a min to talk walk me thru this solution? please

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix this IO and RPC intensive with your client thread. When your button is clicked, start another thread which handles the communication.

In that thread (potentially a separate class) you send the picture and wait for response; at the same time mark your button to be disabled to avoid clicking again. Then when you receive response, send the message again. Afterwards, raise an event back to the GUI thread, enable the button and display the message.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this; call your method sendMessage() after the sendPicMsg() in the "onSuccess()" method